# Export SQL Server results to Sqlite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, ssms

I am performing a query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and would like to export its results to a Sqlite database. I need to do it once, maybe twice, so manual is OK.

There are about 5MM results. I tried csv but it doesn't work out because of the size of the results set and because of problems with escaping the values and commas.

Ideally I'd like SQL Management Studio to do it all, connecting into both the source and the sqlite database in the same query. Is that possible?

Edit: I went with BCP and then SQL Query import tool, worked like a charm.
The bcp command I used was:

```
PS M:\Desktop> bcp "SELECT STATEMENT" queryout output.txt -t ^ -S "SERVER ADDRESS" -T -c
```

Then in SQLite:

```
.separator "^"
.import output.txt table_name
```

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles

Comment: how often do you need to do this?  program/script to issues query/insert int sqlite would be pretty trivial. to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCP (an acronym for Bulk Copy) is the ideal tool for bulk exports. You need to create a format file but it can handle any quantity of data speedily.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Setting the parameters on a sqlcmd run is another option, but you end up essentially hacking CSV and will need to ensure your values don't contain commas, or if you delimit with quotation marks, that you escape quotation marks, and on and on. It is the hack approach.